# Как сделать умный time.sleep()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Мне нужно, чтобы программа при загрузке новой вкладки или процесса выполняла `sleep()`, но этот метод неудобный, так как непонятно, сколько именно времени программа будет загружаться.

Есть ли замена данному методу и какая?

Comment: Какую цель должна выполнять программа? Подробнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Selenuim-a есть метод `WebDriverWait.until()`, по которому можно судить о "готовности" загрузки важной части станицы:

```py
class element_has_css_class(object):
  """An expectation for checking that an element has a particular css class.

  locator - used to find the element
  returns the WebElement once it has the particular css class
  """
  def __init__(self, locator, css_class):
    self.locator = locator
    self.css_class = css_class

  def __call__(self, driver):
    element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)   # Finding the referenced element
    if self.css_class in element.get_attribute("class"):
        return element
    else:
        return False

# Wait until an element with id='myNewInput' has class 'myCSSClass'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(element_has_css_class((By.ID, 'myNewInput'), "myCSSClass"))
```